# systemd timer is running task on every computer restart

Tags: ubuntu, services, systemd-timer

I use Ubuntu.
This is `/etc/systemd/system/myapp.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=...
After=network.target
StartLimitIntervalSec=60

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=no
StartLimitIntervalSec=0
User=myuser
ExecStart=sh /opt/myscript.sh


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and this is the timer:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run every Tuesday ad 8 p.m.

[Timer]
OnCalendar=Tue *-*-* 20:00:00
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

As we see I want to run `myscript.sh` on every Tuesday on 8 p.m. but it runs every time I turn on computer. Maybe this is because of my language on linux set to PL?
Any other ideas, frens?

Answer (score 1):

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

^ remove these lines.  Then run `systemctl disable myapp.service`